# How to stop a numerical counter generated by click events on Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 3 images of a rock, paper and scissor each inside it's own button in a div. I have an array that has the values rock, paper and scissor. When a user clicks on any of the images, the computer randomly selects from the array and compares the value of the array to that clicked by the user(rock-paper-scissor game). If the value selected by the user beats the value randomly selected by the computer, the user scores 1point and computer scores 0point and vice-versa, and the round winner is reported e.g *Player wins the round! Rock beats Scissors* and the scores on each rounds are added on the playerScore and computerScore variables and stored.
I want to play a 10 round game and the first with 10points wins the game, and at this point a reset game button appears below the div which when clicked resets everything to zero and the 10round game can be restarted again.

Now my problem is on reaching the 10points and the winner is reported, the button can still be clicked and their scores are still added. How can I make this stop when either the computerScore or playerScore is equal to 10? or rather how can I remove the click event in this my case? Here is part of the code

```
<div class="buttons">
<button><img src="#" alt="Rock" /></button>
<button><img src="#" alt="Paper" /></button>
<button><img src="#" alt="Scissor" /></button>
</div>
<div>
  <div id="ps">0</div>
  <div id="cs">0</div>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>


let playerScore=0;
let computerScore=0;
let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;
myArray=["Rock","Paper","Scissor"];
function computerPlay(){
  return myArray[Math.floor(Math.random()*myArray.length)];
}
let buttons=document.querySelectorAll(".buttons");
buttons.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener("click",() => {
    const img = button.querySelector("img");
    playerSelection = img.alt.toLowerCase();
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    if(playerScore === 10 || computerScore === 10){
       reportWinner();
       resetGame();
     }
   });
 });
function playRound(playerSelection,computerSelection){
  playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
  computerSelection = computerPlay().toLowerCase();
 if(//player wins the round){
    playerScore = ++playerScore;
    keepPlayerScore();
 }else if(//computer wins the round){
    computerScore = ++computerScore;
    keepComputerScore();
 }else{//display draw}
 }
function keepCS(){
  let computerScores = document.querySelector("#ps");
  computerScores.textContent = computerScore;
}
function keepPS(){
  let playerScores = document.querySelector("#cs");
  playerScores.textContent = playerScore;
}
const output = document.querySelector("#results");
function reportWinner(){
   if(playerScore > computerScore){
     output.textContent = "Congratulations!You have won the game.";
   }else{
     output.textContent = "Computer wins the game!";
      }
   }
function resetGame(){
  //creates a button
  //resets the game on button click. Works perfectly
}
```

Everything works on fine. Even the functions I have used comments on. I just don't know how to stop the counter at 10. If there is anything that needs clarification I am here to clarify. I am new to programming in general and your help is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Right now you check the score after `playRound`, which does not limit your rounds. Disable the buttons inside `reportWinner` or check the score inside `playRound`. There are many ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

### First way :

You can hide those buttons with css propriety.

### The second

You can add to your code 2 functions: a function `startGame()` which will add the eventlistener and a function `endGame()`: which remove the eventlistener

```
function gameRoundHandler() {
    /*A new function that just factorise the callback of your eventListener*/
    const img = button.querySelector("img");
    playerSelection = img.alt.toLowerCase();
    playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
    if(playerScore === 10 || computerScore === 10){
       reportWinner();
       /*Then you call the endGame function to remove the eventListeners*/
       endGame();
       resetGame();
    }
}

function startGame() {
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", gameRoundHandler);
    });
}

function endGame() {
    buttons.forEach((button) => {
        button.removeEventListener("click", gameRoundHandler);
    });
}
```

If you what more details on `removeEventListener` just go [there](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener).
Don't forget to call `startGame()` when the newGame button is pressed.